# How to configure a Mysql datasource in a Cloudbees Java EE6 application?

Tags: mysql, java-ee-6, cloudbees

I'm trying to deploy an existing Jboss 7 war application on the Cloudbees Paas and I'm getting stuck with datasource configuration. Following this dedicated [Cloudbees wiki entry](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/JavaEE) and the [related thread](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/entries/21286801), I end up with the following error (already mentioned by others in the thread) during application startup :

```
javax.resource.ResourceException: Wrong driver class [class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] for this connection URL [jdbc:cloudbees://cbdebate--1]
```

My configuration files are as follows:

**cloudbees-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cloudbees-web-app xmlns="http://www.cloudbees.com/xml/webapp/1">
 <!-- Application ID (formatted CB_ACCOUNT/APPNAME) -->
 <appid>hck/debate</appid>

 <!-- DataSources (use names refererenced via <resource-ref> in WEB-INF/web.xml) -->
    <resource name="jdbc/debate" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        <param name="username" value="myuser" />
        <param name="password" value="mypassword" />
        <param name="url" value="jdbc:cloudbees://cbdebate--1" />

        <!-- Connection Pool settings -->
        <param name="maxActive" value="20" />
        <param name="maxIdle" value="2" />
        <param name="maxWait" value="10000" />
        <param name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </resource>
</cloudbees-web-app>
```

**web.xml** (relevant part)

```
(...)
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/debate</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
(...)
```

**persistence.xml** (relevant part)

```
        <persistence-unit name="debate" transaction-type="JTA">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/debate</jta-data-source>

(... entity classes declaration ...)

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5"/>
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="org.hibernate.worker.batch_size" value="1000" />
        </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Env : Jboss 7, JPA 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Nicolas' answer and some further googling, I managed to get it work. As far as I understand, you cannot use the cloudbees driver `com.cloudbees.jdbc.Driver` from within a Jboss application (and specifically in our case on Cloudbees Java EE 6 server) and have to use the mysql one `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.
As Nicolas stated the `jdbc:cloudbees://[databaseName]` database url uses by convention the cloudbees driver. You need to use the url referencing the actual database (you can find it in the cloudbees database configuration page) in the form of :

```
jdbc:mysql://ec2-AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/[databaseName]
```

the important point here is the jdbc:**mysql**://...

Change the url of the database in cloudbees-web.xml using the form above and it works !

Maybe the cloudbees people could make the documentation a little bit clearer on this particular point

Comment: It tried the same and it worked. But I wonder where I can get the com.cloudbees.jdbc.Drive Jar. I googled for it but I couldnt find it.

Answer (score 0):

To use jdbc:cloudbees:* JDBC URL you need to use com.cloudbees.jdbc.Driver as driver class name.

by convention, each jdbc driver registered on a JVM uses a prefix before it's own specific url infos, so that a jdbc URL is "jdbc::"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I want to try your solution but I'm not sure where in the code (or via cloudbees sdk) I need to specify the reference to the driver class. In my existing code I do NOT specify a jdbc driver class name anywhere. I have tried adding `<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.cloudbees.jdbc.Driver"/>` to my pu declaration in persistence.xml, but it seems doing nothing...

Comment: Also tried to reference the driver class name in cloudbees-web.xml : `<param name="driver" value="com.cloudbees.jdbc.Driver" />`, and alternatively `<param name="driverClassName" value="com.cloudbees.jdbc.Driver" />` without success (same error message)